# find centroid bounded by 2 functions

Tags: calculus

Find the centroid of the region bounded by 
$$f(x) = x^2 - 1$$
$$g(x) = -x^4 + 5x^2 - 4$$
$$-1 \leq x \leq 1$$

I end up with $\left(0, \frac{172}{147}\right)$. Shouldn't the $y$ coordinate be negative?

Comment: Yes, the ordinate of the centroid should be negative and in fact $y_c < -1$, by inspection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because most of the common area lies below y axis.

But, check if you unintentionally have not considered limits for both the other areas 0 < y < 2.

Comment: Could you help me out with this problem? I start out with A = integral of (x^2 - 1) - (-x^4 + 5x^2 - 4) dx from -1 to 1.

I have the y coordinate set as integral of (56/112) * (x^4 - 4x^2 + 3)^2 dx from -1 to 1

Comment: Would it simplify if you consider the difference : $ \int_{-1} ^1  (x^2 - 1) (5 - x^2) dx  $